# C# List Calling to Main

Tags: c#, list

Hey i've got the code:

```
   public static CreditCard FindCard(List<CreditCard> Cust, string Name) 

    {
       foreach(CreditCard cust in Cust)
       {
           if(cust.Name == Name)
           {
               return cust;
           }
       }
       return null;

    }
```

What im trying to do is call it from the Main() which i input a name and returns the first card with the given name. Ive tried for ages would u guys be able to help?

So if i enter "Mike" it'll display his info, ive already got the list set up its just calling it from the main

Comment: you func looks fine. just use it. what's wrong?

Comment: Its cause i wanted to do something like an insert to find that card Something like: String Insert; Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Name"); Insert = Console.ReadLine(); Then after if someone enters "mike" for example they will get all his details and show on the console. Is it possible?

Comment: @user1618490 Why don't you just do it? Once you get the name pass it as a parameter of the method in your question...

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for something like

```
class MyClass
{

 public static CreditCard FindCard(List<CreditCard> Cust, string Name) 

    {
       foreach(CreditCard cust in Cust)
       {
           if(cust.Name == Name)
           {
               return cust;
           }
       }
       return null;

    }

public static int main()
{
// Populate the list
List<CreditCard> cards = new List<CreditCard>{ new CreditCard(...), new CreditCard(...)}

Console.WriteLine("Enter your name: ");
String name = Console.ReadLine();

CreditCard cc = FindCard(cards, name);

if (cc != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cc.Number); // And for all fields in CreditCard class
    ...
}    
Console.ReadKey();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps! exactly what im looking for thanks...so that cc value is just a new value that u created?

Comment: cc is a variable of type CreditCard that contains the value found in the cards list. It may be also null, if person with desired name doesn't exist in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything stopping you from calling it like regular?

`CreditCard mikecard = FindCard(myList, "Mike");`

Comment: Its cause i wanted to do something like an insert to find that card

Something like:

String Insert;

Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Name");
Insert = Console.ReadLine();

Then after if someone enters "mike" for example they will get all his details and show on the console

Comment: @user1618490 Why don't you explain clearly what you want to do in the question?

Comment: @user1618490 You didn't explain that in the question- I'm not a mind reader. My answer answers your question; if you'd like a more specific one you have to be specific about your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest using Linq from Main instead of separate method

```
Cust.FistOrDefault(x => x.Name == Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your code is right but you can also make it as an Extension Method

```
public static EM
{
    public static CreditCard FindCard(this List<CreditCard> Cust, string Name)
    {
       foreach(CreditCard cust in Cust)
       {
           if(cust.Name == Name)
           {
               return cust;
           }
       }
       return null;
    }
}
```

and call it as

```
CreditCard cc = yourList.FindCard("Mike");
```

Comment: Its cause i wanted to do something like an insert to find that card Something like: String Insert; Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Name"); Insert = Console.ReadLine(); Then after if someone enters "mike" for example they will get all his details and show on the console

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the bug is somewhere else in your code. Based on your comments I think you are reading input from the Console. If that's the case it might be adding an extra newline character to the end of the string.

You could use the debugger to check this, but most likely the solution is going to be to trim the input.

For example, you could change the if statement to this:

```
if(cust.Name == Name.Trim())
```

Although that might fix the issue, it's still not very robust. The user could enter any variation of "Mike" or "MIKE" and expect a result. So you should consider doing a case insenstive comparison as well.

```
if(string.Equals(cust.Name, Name.Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```